# I can not move MySQL from Ubuntu 14.04 to new 16.04

Tags: mysql

I loaded a sql dump file made on Ubuntu 14.04 to new server that haves a Ubuntu 16.04. After this whole MySQL do not start.

What is the problem?

I made hard work to reinstall whole MySQL to start from empty.

Comment: The source of the problem might be having different version of MySQL on 14.04 and 16.04

Comment: after you'll know what is the new version of MySQL, you can look for such mysql help page relevant for your version: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: Ok. Is there any suggestions how to make dump.sql file correctly then?

Comment: Then this will help : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: When mysql fails to start it will output an errors showing the problem.  It's too many possibilities for us to try to guess the culprit.  You'll have to show us the actual errors.  Copy text output and append it to your question.

Comment: I found the solution now. after mysql -u root -p < dump.sql must be execute the mysql_upgrade command in command line and the restart the MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See at:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Just ignore the MySQL 5.6.

If you plan to upgrade by reloading a dump file generated from your existing MySQL installation:

```
To generate the dump file, run mysqldump with the --add-drop-table option and without the --flush-privileges option

Stop the old (MySQL 5.6) server

Upgrade the MySQL binaries in place (replace the old binaries with the new ones)

Start the MySQL 5.7 server normally (no special options)

Reload the dump file (mysql < dump_file)

Run mysql_upgrade to upgrade the system tables

Restart the MySQL 5.7 server
```